# ifelse() and paste0() in a vector

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, paste

I've got a vector (mychipvalue) with a single numeric element in it.

If the numeric is 0, I'd like to replace it with "<0.001". If the numeric is not 0 but eg 0.053 I'd like to leave it untouched (keep 0.053).

Thanks for any help!

```
mychipvalue <- 0 
mychipvalue < ifelse(mychipvalue==0,paste0("<0.001"),paste0(mychipvalue))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those calls to `paste0`, but for consistency you should probably report a character in both cases:

```
mychipvalue <- 0 
mychip_report <- ifelse(mychipvalue==0, "<0.001", as.character(mychipvalue))
```

I am using a new character variable to store the output of the `ifelse`, because your original data is numeric, and should probably stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `ifelse`. This will also work

```
mychipvalue[mychipvalue == 0] <- "<0.001"
```

But you end up with a character vector, as mention by Tim Biegeleisen already.

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace`

```
replace(mychipvalue, mychipvalue == 0, "<0.001")
```